# SQL Error = 0 in Joomla 3.x

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am a newbie and I am facing some strange issues with my Joomla 3.1.1 installation. Whenever I try to do a Joomla global check-in, I get the following error:

```
SQL=SELECT module FROM SOM_modules WHERE id = table-name
```

*This is true for all tables

Further, when I try to edit the template custom CSS file from the back-end, I get the following error:

```
SQL=SELECT module FROM SOM_modules WHERE id = 
MTAwNTE6Y3NzL3J0X2RpYW1ldHJpY19yZXNwb25zaXZlLWN1c3RvbS5jc3M=
```

I am facing the same error even when I try to purge Joomla cache.

In all cases, it only says *"An error has occurred"* and there is a preceding 0 before the errors above. I presume that is the SQL error 0.

Kindly help. I have checked the forum and googled for hours but can't find any solution. I have also tried resetting directory and file permissions even to 777 - to test, still no luck.

Config Details:

```
Joomla! version: 3.1.1
PHP version: 5.3.1
MySQL version: 5.5.31
Host: Private VPS
```

Comment: There is '=' char in the id, at the end. So there is a syntax error. MTAwNTE6Y3NzL3J0X2RpYW1ldHJpY19yZXNwb25zaXZlLWN1c3RvbS5jc3M= should be in quotes, like 'MTAwNTE6Y3NzL3J0X2RpYW1ldHJpY19yZXNwb25zaXZlLWN1c3RvbS5jc3M='

Comment: I am sorry for being so dumb but how do I fix this? I mean this is all through the GUI - Joomla admin console. Where do I make these changes?

Comment: you may check your error logs and tell us on which page the error occurs. Try to edit template's css file one more time and look at the error log then.

Comment: Please try to update your joomla installation

Comment: Took time to find out where the error logs are :-( Here is the error : [Tue Jul 16 12:57:06 2013] [error] [client 122.175.28.139] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /srv/www/search-optimize-market.com/public_html/libraries/joomla/updater/adapters/extension.php on line 97, referer: http://search-optimize-market.com/administrator/

Comment: It is already updated to the latest version.. I had used one click update. Don't remember whether I was facing this issue prior to the update.

Comment: I tried re-installing Joomla 3.1.1 through the admin console once again. The installation updates fine but the errors persist.

Comment: Taking a clue from what Alen pointed out, I turned on error reporting in Joomla and set it to development.

Though I did not understand much, I did see quite a few errors - something to do with strict errors caused by one extension (content statistics by Gemini corp).

Disabled all modules, plugins and the component itself and the errors got resolved.

Thanks Mr. Alien for pointing me to the right direction.

Regards, Mangesh

Comment: Finally, this issue is resolved. The issue was with another extension called "Content Statistics". Somehow this extension messed up the entire backend. After uninstalling the extension and all related modules and plugins, the site has become fully functional again. No more SQL=0 errors and I am being able to edit all css files from the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this issue is resolved. The issue was with another extension called "Content Statistics". Somehow this extension messed up the entire backend. It took quite a lot of time to figure out which extension had caused the problem

After uninstalling the extension and all related modules and plugins, the site has become fully functional again. No more SQL=0 errors and I am being able to edit all css files from the backend. –  Mangesh